# SSAS Error : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2016, olap-cube

Getting this error when we are deploying the SSAS solution.
We are using SQL server 2016 SP2+CU2 build.

What confuses me is why it is pointing to old Version=13.0.0.0 in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved after installing the SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi and SQL_AS_AMO.msi on the server.